# use a different index column for loading models in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

In my app users can store private trades in their accounts, such trades are visible only to them.

The Trade model looks like this:

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_user, lambda { |user|
    where(user_id: user.id) unless user.nil?
  }

  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :user
```

the route looks like this:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :trades
end
```

so generating urls like:

```
/users/:user_id/trades/:id/edit
```

Currently for example, if there are three trades stored in the system, a new user, when creating his first trade would be creating a trade with id = 4, and his URL to find it would be: `/users/2/trades/4`

I would like to have the trades to have a new `sequence_number` column and this to be used in the id to find the trades.

So every user will see only his/her trades, and they will be all numbered starting from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the parameter passed for a route, first change in your controller how you find a `trade` given an `:id` for that trade parameter.

```
class TradeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_trade, only [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]
  # Remove @trade = Trade.find(params[:id]) from those four actions

  private
    def find_trade
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @trade = @user.trades.find_by sequence_number: params[:id]
    end
end
```

Then, in your `Trade` model, make `sequence_number` your new parameter.

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    sequence_number
  end
end
```

The [`to_param`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#to-param) method of a model changes the parameter passed in routes for `trades/:id` from `id` to `sequence_number`. So, in your example above for a new user, showing their first trade will be `/users/2/trades/1` rather than `/users/2/trades/4`.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea of having the before action. Why do you you use it only with the `edit` and `show` actions? can't you do it also for `update` and `destroy`?